# Difference in intuition: threeway fixed effects vs interaction of two of the effects

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

my question is a follow-up on a  [previous question of mine:](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/453009/three-way-fixed-effects-vs-combining-two-of-the-effects)

What is the difference in using, as I said in the previous link, I have the possibility of using either area $(a)$, time $(t)$ and sector $(s)$ fixed effects. I want to analyze the impact of the introduction of sectoral tariffs on employment considering $(a,t,s)$ my unit of analysis.

What is the difference on the interpretation of these three models below?

$$y_{ast} = \beta_1 \cdot \tau_{st} + \mu_a + \lambda_s + \delta_t + \epsilon_{ast}$$
$$y_{ast} = \beta_2 \cdot \tau_{st} + \gamma_{as} +  \delta_t + \epsilon_{ast}$$
$$y_{ast} = \beta_3 \cdot \tau_{st} + \omega_{as} +  \alpha_{at} + \epsilon_{ast}$$

What is the difference on the kinds of unobserved effects being 'filtered out'? Are all of them even possible to be estimated?

Comment: What is $\tau$? Is it tariffs (greek letters usually sugges paramters to be estimated). Also they only have index $(s,t)$ does that mean yo do not have any variation in tariffs for different areas? Also do you only have aggregated for $y_{ast}$ measuring employment?

Comment: Yes, they are tariffs. Since all areas are on the same country, there is no variation by area, which in my case is a city. I dont have anything more disaggregated geographically than that.